# Access-VBA for loops

Tags: for-loop, ms-access, vba

I am quite new to VB coding but I do understand some of the basics. I want to create a loop that checks the value within 8 text boxes and enabled a tick box next to the respected text box if it not blank. I am not quite sure on the syntax. I have 8 text boxes called Textbox1 : Textbox8 and 8 checkboxes with names checkbox1-8. This is the code I have already but I just need a bit of help with the syntax.

```
 For i = 1 To 8

 If Textbox(i) = "" Then
 checkbox(i).enabled = false
 else
 checkbox(i).enabled = true

 End If

 Next
```

Comment: Create a string: `"Textbox" & i`  Use that string to refer to the item in the form's `Controls` collection: `If Me.Controls("Textbox" & i).Value = "" Then`  Use the same strategy for your check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
 For i = 1 To 8
     Me.Controls("checkbox" & i).Enabled = (Nz(Me.Controls("Textbox" & i).Value) <> "")
 Next
```